# Why is my exception handling code not handling exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some C# code that pulls down a remote website using the HttpWebRequest class.  I'm handling errors with a try/catch, but some errors (like Webrequest and IOException) don't seem to be getting "caught" with the way I have it setup:

```
try
{
    StartScrap("http://www.domain.com");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogError(ex.ToString();
}


private void StartScrap(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseText = String.Empty;

        using (StreamReader readerStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            responseText = readerStream.ReadToEnd(); <-- I will sometimes get a Webexception error here that won't get caught above and stops the code
        }
    }
}
```

Update: There is more to the code, so maybe it is something outside of the code I posted?  I am basically using this code in a Windows Application on a form that has a NotifyIcon. I'm using the Timer class to run the code at a certain timer interval.  This is how I have it setup:

```
    public TrayIcon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TrayIcon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StartScrap("http://www.domain.com");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            StartTimer();
        }
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        Timer Clock = new Timer();
        Clock.Interval = 600000;
        Clock.Start();
        Clock.Tick += new EventHandler(TrayIcon_Load);
    }
```

Comment: Is this exactly the code that starts your screen scraper? If you're running this in background thread and the try/catch is on the main thread then you would get the result you're getting.

Comment: The code above is missing a closing bracket in LogError(ex.ToString(); (it should never compile).

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you mean by "stops the code"? Are you running in a debugger by any chance? My guess is that if you run outside the debugger - or just hit "run" again in the debugger - you'll get into the catch block with no problems. Alternatively, go into the debugger settings and change at which point the debugger steps in.

Of course, if this *isn't* happening in the debugger, we just need more information about exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: In debug mode, it hits that line of code, but when it's running, I get the Windows error dialog then asks if I want to see the details, Continue or Cancel (wish I had a screenshot of it).

Comment: LogError must be throwing an exception then.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that LogError is throwing an exception?

Comment: No, because I don't have anything written in the LogError functions, its just stub code for now.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking I am not sure what exactly happening but I will suggest you to go with [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).(Error Logging Modules and Handlers)

[Here](http://www.asp.net/learn/hosting/tutorial-14-cs.aspx) is a step by step How to for ELMAH.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found out I was calling the wrong function my Timer class and it was bypassing the event handler.